# Microsoft Graph Api Upload Large File in a folder

Tags: c#, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to upload files bigger than 4 mb into a folder in a Sharepoint List using the LargFileUploadTask. The code seems to create temp files after the PostAsync in the "cities" folder. I see a file created i.e. ~tmphamilton.png . But when the UploadAsync gets called it fails, and returns "The ressource could not be found"

The code works fine when I remove the folder path when creating the uploadSession

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

```
   // create an upload session
var uploadSession = await graphClient.Sites("site id").Drive().Root().ItemWithPath("cities\hamilton.png").CreateUploadSession().Request().PostAsync();

var maxSliceSize = 320 * 1024; // 320 KB - Change this to your slice size. 5MB is the default.

var largeFileUploadTask = new LargeFileUploadTask(uploadSession, stream, maxSliceSize);

// upload away with relevant callback
DriveItem itemResult = await largeFileUploadTask.UploadAsync( progress );
```

Comment: Have you made sure previous session for the same named file are closed / expired. I've had similar issues when some aspect of an upload failed, then no further uploads would work for ~4hrs? until the failed (and unclosed) sessions had expired.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the max. upload size setting in your WebApplication is larger than your file. Depends on the upload location and SharePoint Version it could be as less as 50MB. On Premise, it can be set at *CentralAdmin->Application Management->Web Application xy->General Settings*

Check also https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/archive/blogs/bgeoffro/list-attachments-over-50mb-need-more-than-an-increase-in-maximum-upload-size

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to successfully upload the file to the root of the Document Library?  See code below.

```
string siteId = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("SiteId");
string libraryName = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("LibraryName");
string fileName = filePath.Substring(filePath.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);

var uploadSession = await graphServiceClient.Sites[siteId].Lists[libraryName].Drive.Root
.ItemWithPath(fileName)
.CreateUploadSession(uploadProps)
.Request()
.PostAsync();
```

Comment: Yes it works find uploading to the root, but not to a folder
i.e. ItemWithPath("hamilton.png")  works but ItemWithPath("cities\hamilton.png") doesn't

Answer (score 0):

It does work for me with Graph 3.1.4 and Java, took me a while to get it to work, but its uploading the file >4MB quite performing...

// itemPath is something like "/myFolder/DailyUpload/"

```
  public CompletableFuture UploadFileToSharePoint(String idSite, String parentId, String itemPath, String fileName, InputStream file) {
    final List<Option> options = new LinkedList<Option>();
    try {
      return  mClient
                .sites(idSite)
                .drive()
                .root()
                .itemWithPath(itemPath+ Build.ID.toUpperCase()+"/"+fileName)
                .createUploadSession(
                        DriveItemCreateUploadSessionParameterSet.newBuilder()
                        .withItem(new DriveItemUploadableProperties())
                        .build())
                .buildRequest(options)
                .postAsync().thenCompose(uploadSession -> {

            byte[] data = null;
            try {
                    byte[] buff = new byte[file.available()];
                    int bytesRead = 0;
                    ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    while ((bytesRead = file.read(buff)) != -1) {
                        bao.write(buff, 0, bytesRead);
                    }
                    data = bao.toByteArray();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (data != null && data.length>0) {
                final InputStream uploadFile = new ByteArrayInputStream(data); //"{\"hehe\":\"haha\"}".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                try {
                    final long fileSize = (long) uploadFile.available();
                    LargeFileUploadTask<DriveItem> largeFileUploadTask = new LargeFileUploadTask<DriveItem>(uploadSession,
                            mClient, uploadFile, fileSize, DriveItem.class);
                    // If everything is fine, the procedure returns a DriveItem with the item already
                    return largeFileUploadTask.uploadAsync();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            return null;
        });
    }
    catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        Log.d("GraphHelper", "UploadFileToSharePoint failed: "+ e.getMessage());
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(false);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps others